# Flash movie becomes while blank after switching browser tabs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome

I have the following issue:

When I load my flash app in Google Chrome everything works fine. But when I switch to another tab in browser, wait a bit and switch back instead of my flash app I see white area. Moreover, when I do right-click on it I see flash menu (that one you normally see on right-click).

I see this strange issue only in Google Chrome.

I have Google Chrome 19.0.1084.56 and it runs on Mac.

Any ideas and thoughts are welcome!

Comment: Do you have a link where we can see the problem? Is your swf doing something relating to framerate (framerate is greatly reduced when you are away from the tab with the swf in)?

Comment: No, I do nothing with framerate except it is set to 60 fps.